# React Native Update Object Array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this data object using mobx, and i am unable to update the values array. Would appreciate some help on this matter.

```
   @observable data = {
      dataSets: [{
        values: [0],
        label: 'X Axis',
      }, {
        values: [0],
        label: 'Y Axis',
      }, {
        values: [0],
        label: 'Z Axis',
      }]
```

Values of the console logs

```
console.log(dataSets.length)
3
console.log(dataSets[0].values.length)
1
```

It was my mistake from the start, i updated the object instead of the array itself. Thank you, answer is solved with the following.

```
const {dataSets} = this.data
dataSets[0].values.push(xArr)
```

Comment: Did you still get the error? after updating the question ? your error picture said `dataSets[0].push`, but `dataSets[0]` is an object.

Comment: log details like dataSets.length , dataSets[0].values.length

Comment: I mistyped question. Yes, i am still getting the error

Comment: Can you pls update the error image too ?

Comment: Maybe try to use `data.dataSets[0].values.push(xArr)`